# Scala pattern match on ADTs may not warn on unreachable code

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types

I've got a simple ADT (Algebraic Data Type) encoded as:

```
sealed trait TrafficLight
case object Red extends TrafficLight
case object Green extends TrafficLight
case object Yellow extends TrafficLight
```

Say, I have a function that returns the name of the colour of a TrafficLight:

```
  def getColour(tf: TrafficLight): String = tf match {
    case Red    => "red"
    case Green  => "green"
    case Yellow => "yellow"
  }
```

This works as expected. Now I've matched all cases of TrafficLight in the above function. If I introduce a default match down the bottom of the same method:

```
  def getColour(tf: TrafficLight): String = tf match {
    case Red    => "red"
    case Green  => "green"
    case Yellow => "yellow"
    case other  => "unknown" //this should not be unreachable
  }
```

the compiler does not warn me that `case other` is unreachable. I have also enabled the compiler flag: `-Ywarn-dead-code`. Does this mean that Scala can't infer that I've covered all the possible values of the TrafficLight ADT?

This seems unlikely because if I change the definition of `getColour` to:

```
def blah(tf: TrafficLight): String = tf match {
  case Red    => "red"
  case Green  => "green"
}
```

the compiler warns me that I've missed a case:

```
> match may not be exhaustive.
> [error] It would fail on the following input: Yellow
> [error]   def blah(tf: TrafficLight): String = tf match {
```

I'm using Scala 2.12.5

Is this a bug or have I made a wrong assumption?

Answer (score 2):

You did not covered all possible variants of `TrafficLight` you just covered all named variants, but you can still pass anonymous class object as argument fe.:

```
getColour(new TrafficLight {})
```

Comment: error: *"illegal inheritance from sealed trait TrafficLight"*. What would the `sealed` be good for, otherwise?

Comment: Well, in that case `sealed` will prevent you from passing anonymous object from other file, so above works only for calls made in same file. But there still are other cases like passing `null` as parameter.

Comment: There are also odd corner cases such as creating the anonymous new `TrafficLight` object in the same file as `TrafficLight` (e.g. `def apply() = new TrafficLight {}` in the companion object.) This is legal even with a sealed trait, and I don't think the compiler can exclude that you've done something like this.

Comment: The compiler should be able to detect all extensions of `TrafficLight` in the same file, because it's `sealed`. So it should be able to detect something like 
`new TrafficLight{}`, and then say my match is not exhaustive:
    [error] It would fail on the following input: $anon()
    [error]   def blah(tf: TrafficLight): String = tf match {